# Route is not detected when route id is not assigned? Does CamelContext loses the route information?

Tags: apache-camel

With below route configuration with routeId defined as route1, route2 and ***we intentionally omit the routeId for the 3rd route***.Camel will auto-gen a routeId with format as route + count for you if you didn't define it.

This seems to cause some routes to be missed as camelContext stores the routes with a Set structure internally. Would like to double confirm my understanding here.
May I know if anyone encountered the same?

```
    from(INBOUND_ENDPOINT).routeId("route1")
            .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly).threads(5)
            .bean(ThroughputMeasurer.class);

    from(OUTBOUND_ENDPOINT).routeId("route2")
    .setExchangePattern(ExchangePattern.InOnly).threads(5)
    .bean(ThroughputMeasurer.class);

    from("direct:processOrder").bean(
            ThroughputMeasurer.class);
```

Comment: Do you say that the routes without the route id is missed or occasionaly missed and thus your functionality does not work? . Please increase the clarity

Comment: How do you run your camel app. Maven run for testing or in a container like sevice mix or jboss fuse

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have found a bug. I tested with Camel v2.14.0.

Route definitions:

```
 from("direct:start1")
     .routeId("route1")
     .log("route1: ${body}");

 from("direct:start2")
      .routeId("route2")
      .log("route2: ${body}");

 from("direct:start3") // no route id!
      .log("route3: ${body}");
```

Testing:

```
 ProducerTemplate template = context.createProducerTemplate();
 template.sendBody("direct:start1", "World!");
 template.sendBody("direct:start2", "World!");
```

This leads to following exception:

> Caused by: org.apache.camel.component.direct.DirectConsumerNotAvailableException: No consumers available on endpoint: Endpoint[direct://start1]

If the `"direct:start3"` route is deleted or the ID `"route1"` is renamed, then everything works as expected.

**Edit:**

I opened a bug report: [CAMEL-7986](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-7986).

Comment: Yup, seems that Camel could only detects duplicated routeId if those routeIds are defined with routeId() method.